# Are there scripts available for AIMD?

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, aimd, abinit

I need to determine which of two electrolyte is the best for a hydrogen fuel cell. As far as I understand, the first thing to do is to compute their ionic diffusion coefficient and to compare (the best electrolyte being the one with the highest ionic diffusion coefficient).
I have never done an AIMD script. Would anyone know of existing scripts that I could adapt (even parts that I could try to complete)?

Any help appreciated, many thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I see you used the the tag 'abinit' so I assume you want to do AIMD with abinit. Abinit's documentation is incredible and you should be able to make a lot of progress by looking there! See e.g. the topics page [here](https://docs.abinit.org/topics/MolecularDynamics/) and the tutorial on parallelism with MD which gives example input files and results [here](https://docs.abinit.org/tutorial/paral_moldyn/).

The 'ab-initio' part really just means that the forces are calculated with DFT vs classical MD where the forces use a classical force-field model. The MD-part (i.e. velocity integration) is very simple. Some codes do more sophisticated things than others, e.g. evolve the electronic coordinates in time using the Car-Parrinello method to avoid the SCF loop. Others extrapolate the density, etc. etc. Similarly, some codes implement more thermostats than others with more user control.

I think the MD code in abinit is less refined than other codes. If you want a more sophisticated *MD code*, you could try CP2K which also has a lot of [examples](https://www.cp2k.org/exercises). It is based on local-orbitals and is a little more geared towards molecules than solids, but I have used it to model crystals before. Quantum ESPRESSO is a good free software that uses plane waves. It has examples distributed with the source code and [slides](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/tutorials/shanghai-2013/hands-on-aimd/). Non-free codes like VASP have very sophisticated thermostats. See [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Molecular_dynamics_calculations). VASP also has example code in the [tutorials](https://www.vasp.at/tutorials/latest/md/).

Hopefully this helps get you started!

Comment: An excellent answer!

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to Tyler Sterling's excellent answer, there is also the CASTEP plane-wave DFT program, which is free for academic use (in fact any non-commercial use) and has quite a lot of MD functionality, including:

- a range of ensembles (NVE, NVT, NPT, NPH)
- several thermostats, including a fast equilibration thermostat (Andersen)
- path-integral MD for quantum nuclear motion

See the [documentation site MD pages](https://castep-docs.github.io/castep-docs/documentation/Molecular_Dynamics/keywords/) for more details.

I've used CASTEP's MD quite a lot for a wide range of simulations, and I think it's quite easy to use (I'm a CASTEP developer though, so I'm not the best person to judge that!).

Edit: I should have added where to get the licence! It's here:

https://licences.stfc.ac.uk/product/castep

Comment: I have been meaning to try CASTEP for DFPT (I frequently use euphonic which interfaces with CASTEP), so it is good to know it is free to use!

Comment: @TylerSterling we'd be delighted if you gave it a try. We'd also welcome any feedback on usability, speed etc. those are my personal areas of interest, but it's always tricky to know what people would like.

Comment: @PhilHasnip It seems like we need to convince our advisors/faculty members to acquire the license. Is it possible for a grad student to obtain the license or some kind of trial license using the institutional email so that we can convince our superiors after giving it some trial?